# Object construction is atomic or not?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Is object construction in java ThreadSafe ?Please refer following code snippet.

```
//We have some peace of code
public ABCClass(SomeOtherClass obj) {

    obj.setState(XYZ);

}
```

Then somewhere 50 threads are concurrently construing ABCClass objects. while construction we are changing the state of SomeOtherClass's object.

My question is this construction process is atomic or threads will see stale state of  SomeOtherClass's object as they are being shared among all ABCClass's instance.

**EDIT :** obj object is being shared in all constructors.

```
class SomeOtherClass{

private Status state;

public void setState(Status st){

    this.state=st;
}   

} 
//  Test Class
class TestClass{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final SomeOtherClass smc=new SomeOtherClass();

    for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ABCClass(smc);

            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You declare `ob` as parameter of ABCClass, but how about `obj`. Show me the declaration of `obj`.

Comment: @LukasEder: This is just a case.

Comment: @nnhthuan: Sorry,typo error. they are same

Comment: Okie. :) I saw your modification.

Comment: [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html) may be some useful reading for you (about avoiding letting `this` escape during construction)

Comment: IMHO, this is a wrong description since you're mutating the state of SomeOtherClass inside ABCClass c-tor in a non thread-safe mode. If some kind of sync mech is made then SomeOtherClass is thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with constructors, but with sharing that `SomeOtherClass obj` amongst threads and concurrently mutating it -- and that IS a concurrency issue. You must make sure that all mutations of this object are thread-safe.

## Update

Code that proves the point from comments below:

```
public class Test {
  static Test t1;
  public Test() {
    System.out.println("Constructing Test");
    t1 = this;
    try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (Exception e) {}
    System.out.println("Almost done");
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new Thread() { public void run() { new Test(); }}.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println(t1);
  }
}
```

Comment: My question is whether construction process is atomic or not?

Comment: No, the construction process is not atomic. In fact, that very notion is ill-defined. Do you mean by it that the effect would be as if all constructors in Java contended for a JVM-global lock?

Comment: No , If object has not been yet created it won't be visible to threads.

Comment: And what do you count as object creation? If it's visible to one thread, it can be visible to any other thread just as well. Did you hear about the `leaked this` problem?

Comment: that means , in case of object construction also we can assume constructor as a unsynchronized method and then we need to take care of concurrency.

Comment: Just don't mistake `new X()` for a simple constructor call. There's a lot more executing than constructor code when you execute that -- all instance initializers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think the construction process is atomic,,,,memory allocation and initialization are compound actions. Also, if you pass in the same object OBJ for constructing object in lets say 50 threads, then the method obj.setState(XYZ) should be thread-safe...thats all you want to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Object will be created in each thread's context and it will be atomic, No thread can see other thread's state so no side effects but if object/instanceVariable(static) is shared among threads then there, you may need to provide concurrency control

Comment: So you mean to say construction is not an atomic operation?

Answer (score 0):

If each thread is creating new object and modifying its state, then concurrency is not an issue, as each thread has its own object to work on.

Problem arises if a single object is being modified by more than one thread. In such a case, you need to provide a synchronized way of accessing the shared object.

Read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Answer (score 0):

If your SomeOtherClass's object is inside the ABCClass and it is static, you can synchronize on this static object.

If your SomeOtherClass's object is inside the ABCClass and it is not static, so you don't care about the synchronuzation, because each object instantiate once only - that means the construction is call once only for an object of ABCClass.